# Routing problem with Angular 5 and router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
I have this structure :
- src
    |
    |- app
        |
        |- moduleDashboard
        |   |
        |   |- DashboardComponent
        |   dashboard.routing.ts
        |
        |- moduleCustomer
            |
            |- CustomerListComponent
            |- CustomerAllDetailComponent
            customer.routing.ts         
        app.routing.ts

in app.routing.ts
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },{
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './moduleDashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
        },{
            path: 'client',
            loadChildren: './moduleCustomer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
        }]
        },{
            path: '',
            component: AuthLayoutComponent,
            children: [{
                path: 'pages',
                loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
            }]
        }
];

in dashboard.routing.ts
export const DashboardRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    children: [ {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent
  }]
}];

in customer.routing.ts
export const CustomerRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
        children: [ {
            path: 'clil',
            component: CustomerListComponent
        },{
            path: 'clid/:customerReference',
            component: CustomerAllDetailComponent                    
        }]
    }];
```

All the navigation is working fine but n a function in `customer-list.component.ts` I'd like be redirect to a specific path. 
I tried several solution but all the time I'm redirected to path dashboard.

I tried these solutions :

```
    myFunction() {
//myCustomerReference variable contain 1900001
        this.router.navigate([`/client/clid/1900001}`]);
        this.router.navigate([`/client/clid/1900001`], {relativeTo: this.route});
        this.router.navigate(['client/clid/:customerReference', myCustomerReference], {relativeTo: this.route});
        this.router.navigate(['client/clid', 1900001], {relativeTo: this.route});
    }
```

and more but I never hit `http://localhost:4200/client/clid/1900001`

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible to create a working example of this in stackblitz? Also how is `myFunction()` getting called? Which path are you on at that time?

Comment: Where do you use 'CustomerRoutes' after you define it? Please add the whole code located at 'customer.routing.ts'

Answer (score 0):

You got bad routing it should looks like:

in app.routing.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './moduleDashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
  { path: 'customer', loadChildren: './moduleCustomer/customer.module#CustomerModule'}, // its an client or customer ?
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule' }
  ];
```

in dashboard.routing.ts

```
export const DashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

in customer.routing.ts

```
export const CustomerRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CustomerComponent , children: [ // customerRoute have to have his own Component may be this is main problem.
    { path: 'clil', component: CustomerListComponent },
    { path: 'clid/:customerReference', component: CustomerAllDetailComponent }
  ]
}];
```

And what is this `AdminLeyoutComponent` ? if it have no his own `path:` past it to template as `<app-admin-leyout></app-admin-leyout>`.

if you want to pass all routes thro the `AdminLayoutComponent`:

in AdminLayoutComponent.html:

```
<div class="some-code">
<ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

in AppComponent.html:

```
<app-admin-layout>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-admin-layout>
```

Comment: The strange think after an http request to add a customer, I do in the http success : this.router.navigate([`/client/clie/${data["customerReference"]}`]); and that's work.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's very difficult to explain it's a theme I bought. But there is a free version here : https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-dashboard-angular may be you can take a look. If I understand all the route are children of AdminLayoutComponent component, and there is a login module children of AuthLayoutComponent. At any time you talk about router.navigate syntax may be I have to specify the AdminLayoutComponent somewhere ?

Comment: I downloaded it and there are no any AmdminLayoutComponent ;]

Comment: In this app only AppComponent is an parent of all routes from app.routing.ts file.

Comment: I know i start learning Angular 6+ and project is in Angular 4. So maybe I'm wrong about routing on this version.